# YUI equivalent to removeAttribute() JavaScript method

Tags: javascript, yui

What is YUI equivalent to below JavaScript code?

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").removeAttribute("id");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you're meaning YUI2. But in case you meant YUI3, it's exactly like the DOM method:

```
Y.one('#myDiv').removeAttribute('someAttribute');
```

You can read a list of all Y.Node methods in the API docs: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html

Answer (score 0):

YUI2 has no this one but the follows:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Dom.html#method_getAttribute
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Dom.html#method_setAttribute

EDIT: Why don't you like removeAttribute? It has fully supported across browsers:http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t118

Answer (score 0):

`YAHOO.util.Dom.get("myDiv").removeAttribute("id");`

Comment: YUI does not have removeAttribute method